How to combine `react-hook-form` with nextJS `searchParams`
I have a page with some filtering implemented as below:

const filterHomeworksSchema = z.object({
  sort: selectItem,
  minPrice: price,
  maxPrice: price,
  solutionFormats: arrayOfSelectItems,
  domainsIds: arrayOfSelectItems,
  theoremsIds: arrayOfSelectItems,
  theoremsExact: checkbox,
  definitionsIds: arrayOfSelectItems,
  definitionsExact: checkbox,
  tagsIds: arrayOfSelectItems,
  tagsExact: checkbox,
  authorsIds: arrayOfSelectItems,
});

export type FilterHomeworksSchemaType = z.infer<typeof filterHomeworksSchema>;

export default function HomeworksPage({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: FilterHomeworksSchemaType;
}) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ page: 1, pageSize: 10 });

  const {
    register,
    control,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FilterHomeworksSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(filterHomeworksSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      sort: undefined,
      minPrice: searchParams.minPrice || undefined,
      maxPrice: searchParams.maxPrice || undefined,
      solutionFormats: [],
      domainsIds: [],
      definitionsIds: [],
      definitionsExact: false,
      theoremsIds: [],
      theoremsExact: false,
      tagsIds: [],
      tagsExact: false,
      authorsIds: [],
    },
  });

  const filters = watch();
  ...


I'm wondering how can I update page URL when filters are updated? So changing max price to 10 should add to URL maxPrice=5 and updating tagsIds should also somehow serialize it and add to URL. How to do it?
